# Facebook Graph API giving an unknown OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I send a request to https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=*(access code goes here)* Facebook gives me this error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred."
   }
}
```

Every other API call works. If anybody knows anything about this issue, please help me.

Comment: The same error happens right now to my mobile app,without having changed code... it is not the first time Facebook change things without notice at all ...in my case https://graph.facebook.com/me is failing while other graph resource seems working

Comment: today they have removed last slash ....http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=103711

Comment: There is currently a bug report related to a very similar issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/525301577527928

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Facebook does not have very good error messages...

Apparantly, "An unknown error has occurred" means that I did not have valid permissions to access the user's news feed.

You have to include "read_stream" in your scope, or else facebook will reject your request with an ambiguous error message.

I <3 you facebook API

Comment: I don't <3 you facebook API, the exact opposite.

Answer (score 6):

*In addition* to the other answers provided here...

In our production app (working with thousands of access tokens for several years), it appears that we occasionally get this error due to a temporary glitch in the API.  I'm still not sure what the root cause is, but simply retrying the API call a few minutes later seems to consistently resolve the issue for us.

Answer (score 4):

I get this error when the access token is the *application's* token.  With the *user-specific* token, the api calls succeed.

Before the oauth upgrade, the application's token worked.  The user-specific token worked and usually returned even more data.

Of course with facebook there's no way of knowing whether the current behavior (fails when using application token) is a bug or just the new way.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, the parameter is `access_token`, not `access`.

Comment: @user434565 Why not edit your question and correct your typo?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and fixed it. For me, I was passing a single JSON object in the "batch" field, but Facebook wanted a JSON array.

For example, this will work, because it has a JSON array denoted by square brackets:

```
POST /v2.11 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{
"access_token":"YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
"batch":[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}]
}
```

This will not, because there is no JSON array denoted by square brackets:

```
POST /v2.11 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{
"access_token":"YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
"batch":{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}
}
```