# Images in imageurls are appearing in small size in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20")+"&source="+imageUrl
```

I am using the above graph api,to post message and image to my wall.

The image in imageUrl  is of size 240*320.But when I posted it,it is not posting as an image,it is posting in a rectangular box in facebook.It is something like some adds posting in facebook ex: luck percentage post where the image is in small size in a rectangular box.

How can I post large image by using the image Urls?

I tried to post a image of this image url directly in facebook,then image is in large size.

I think,when we post by using Urls it is getting like this.

As I am using graph api,it is asking imageurls,so find no solution except creating urls.

Help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: check this ans you got your solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12293604/1168654

Comment: I want to use graph api as I mentioned above,please tell the solution for this case.I used both "source" and "picture" tags,but the result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

There is written:

```
...will help accentuate photos with a larger display in Ticker, Timeline, and News Feed.
```

This needs additional approval by FB and will only be approved if your App is posting "User Generated Photos". This means photos shoot with a camera or mobile phone or anything comparable.

Comment: I used like below but I am getting Bad Request as response,    String res=  UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20")+"&image[0][url]="+imageUrl
            + "image[0][user_generated]="+"true"+"&privacy="+result);

Comment: I added this ("&image[0][url]="+imageUrl
            + "image[0][user_generated]="+"true") to my request to facebook,but it is giving me Bad request as response,Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @user1891910 Ok I think I understand...  
Let me ask some question to verify your problem.
Which image type are you trying to link to? Maybe you can share to url?  
Does facebook serve the thumbnail image via     http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/...
or 
http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/...

Comment: http://purple2.com/beerbro/images/20121214073406.jpg  This is the image I am  using,but this image is taken by facebook as Thumbnail and displaying as rectangular box ( as we see in link posts in our facebook)

Comment: @user1891910 and depending on your use-case. I suggest you swiching to http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ for photo posting on a users feed.

Comment: https://s-platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=160971530656135&v=1&size=z&cksum=498dc3ca0c42e45e94e9685beef9ca42&src=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fimx-picsfriend.cotssl.net\u00252Fcrowdsocial\u00252Fdailypic\u00252F20121213\u00252F95052s.jpg    I Am getting this image in my newsfeed data

Comment: @user1891910 I tested your photo and i get execatly the same results for posting via API or manually. Both use http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDDGe3mGBV3J1PP&w=155&h=114&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpurple2.com%2Fbeerbro%2Fimages%2F20121214073406.jpg as thumbnail.  
  
If you want larger photos you have to upload them into users album which require additional permissions.  
  
Then you can use the "User-generated-photo" settings to create the largest photos possible as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I think facebook is taking the image as Thumbnail by default,how to change this

Comment: Can you tell the reason why graph api is taking thumbnail images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21122/discussion-between-user1891910-and-robin-webdev)

Comment: First of all, the thing you are doing is posting a "Link" to the image.
The docs say when you send a post to /ID/feed you can set a param "message". Should be clear. Then you have the opportunity to set "link" to any valid url. Now facebook generates a thumbnail and appends the link to your post. Furthermore you can set "picture" to any url of an image to set the thumbnail by yourself. Setting "picture" to null stops facebook from showing an thumbnail.