# "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", "type": "OAuthException", facebook sdk 4 php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This was working perfecty till yesterday. But today got error while request facebook api data. Have been using curl to request the link

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/?access_token=YOURTOKENHERE.
```

I use a valid token with app. This is really weird. How come code suddenly stoped.

```
{
 "error": {
   "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API giving an unknown OAuthException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269184/facebook-graph-api-giving-an-unknown-oauthexception)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably a bug of the Facebook API, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486654544831076/