# How get or check facebook user id from mobile token in server

Tags: java, android, facebook, ionic-framework

I login in my ionic2 app in facebook and get response like this:

```
{
  token: "iuiouoi.weewe.weioioioi", // this is example token
  signup: "false"
}
```

And can get user id.

Then I want store user id in my database and send this token and user id to the server. I want check token and user id on server and make this request:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=iuiouoi.weewe.weioioioi`

But after this request I have exeption:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Bad signature",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "Bg4sWambfPx"
  }
}
```

Can I check user id and this token for complience in my server, after login in application?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding please read:-

[Facebook Graph API giving an unknown OAuthException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269184/facebook-graph-api-giving-an-unknown-oauthexception)

["message": "An unknown error has occurred.", "type": "OAuthException", facebook sdk 4 php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558824/message-an-unknown-error-has-occurred-type-oauthexception-facebook)

If these also not work than read this link because its also a bug in FB.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486654544831076/