# "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later." ERROR when requesting facebook api for page feed

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been running a script that gets facebook feed by requesting the facebook api for a bunch of PAGEIDS. This script runs every 3 hours making 3 to 4 requests per PAGEID returning mostly 25 posts per request by default. It was working smoothly for the last two months but all of a sudden its returning this error kind of randomly for different PAGEIDS.

JSON Error given below:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "is_transient": true,
      "code": 2,
      "fbtrace_id": "BgbUGNjLTSW"
   }
}
```

Sample API request below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/feed/?since=LASTWEEKDATE&fields=id,object_id,picture,from,message,created_time,shares,type,status_type,link,comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I ran the script manually through the prompt, scheduled it as a cronjob & even called the API request on the browser. All these methods returned the Error randomly & its giving mixed results everyday. So if I call the request on browser once, it fails BUT when I refresh the url it works. I am using multiple facebook app accesstokens & they all fail randomly.

What is the issue here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems that FB's authentication system is giving you trouble. Make sure your api keys have the needed permissions in their scope. Like ads_management. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269184/facebook-graph-api-giving-an-unknown-oauthexception

Comment: I checked the keys.Those requests still return proper responses with feed most of the time, they wouldnt if there were permissions & scope issues.

Comment: If you try to get the feed for a page_id with ads and your key doesnt have ads_management permission, you might get the OAuth exception because of that. Just a hypothesis.